# nedb: how to get docs out of find() function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, nedb

I encapsulated the nedb module in self-defined object:

```js
var Record = function() {
  var Datastore = require('nedb');
  this.db = new Datastore({filename: 'record'});
  this.db.loadDatabase();
};
```

And I want to define my own function to get all the objects in the database:

```js
Record.prototype.getItems = function() {
  var items = null;
  this.db.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    items = docs;
  });
  return items;
};
```

However, the variable "items" can't be assigned to variable "docs" and is always "null". I realize that this is caused by the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.
But how can I get the variable "docs" out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises and async/await syntax to omit the callback

```
Record.prototype.getItems = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.db.find({}, (err, doc) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        });
    });
}
```

And then retrieve the data like so

```
async function whatever(){
    const data = await Record.getItems();
}
```

I would also recommend using this wrapper module for nedb, called [NeDB-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nedb-promises) ,which includes convenient features like built-in support for promises and events

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback function that retrieves the data when it's ready, like this:

```
Record.prototype.getItems = function(callback) {
    this.db.find({}, callback);
};
```

Then use it:

```
const record = new Record();
record.getItems((err, docs) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(docs);
});
```